# A way to automate a website user with AI?

Tags: automated-tests

Call me silly, but I'm looking for a way to use a website automatically, same time every day, but with the capability of responding to many different situations (all of them can be predicted so I can do it myself, I just need it to recognise it) The problem is im very new to programming as a whole and I'm totally lost on where to start with this project... can anyone help? Is it even possible for someone at my level?

Comment: It is probably going to be not possible for you to do if you are new to programming. I suggest you learn basic/advanced programming concepts first and then tackle AI after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be simple. no. AI programming is very advanced and requires a lot of in-depth knowledge of programming. You might be able to hack together a solution using selenium, which is a tool for testing the UI.

There is also the possibility to make a bot that clicks on specific locations on the screen. they cannot respond to what is actually on the screen however. If the website is a bit slower than normal things can go wrong as well. That would not be the best solution.

Comment: Ahhh yes, that's similar to what I was talkin about! Thank you!! And yeah, hahah, I thought about that as well- the best idea I had was something that could recognise text or specific elements on a page and would activate those specifically, but that's prolly out of my range of skill. Still, I hope you've a great day!!